# Authorship in work dedicated to the public domain

Tags: copyright, creative-commons, public-domain, authorship

I want to dedicate a work I created to the Public Domain using Creative Commons CC0 PD Dedication, and I was wondering how the fact that I'm the author of the work is affected.

I understand that anybody could use or redistribute my work for any purpose, and that they don't need to give me credit. However, I was wondering three things:

- Can someone claim that I'm *not* the author of the work?
- Can someone claim *they* are the author of the work?
- Can some take a verbatim copy of my work and relicense it? (I'm asking this on the assumption that only the author or copyright holder of a work can apply a license to it)

Comment: For your last question, please note that there's nothing in the CC0 license that forbids a downstream user from applying her own terms and/or additional restrictions of her own. So it seems more a question of semantics -- you might say she "relicensed it" but she could simply say she's using you work fully in accordance with the CC0 terms (i.e. she's not breaking any of the CC0 rules, which you licensed to her). In technical terms we say it's "compatible" with another license. I.e. CC0 is 'compatible' with CC-BY-ND, for example.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I'm more concerned about the other questions tough. I do not personally care if someone redistributes my work under CC-BY-ND or even a closed license, but, I am concerned whether someone could own or act like they owned the copyright by, for example, selling the rights to my work to a third party. I understand that CC0 is compatible with other licenses, but, if license A is an exclusive license, i.e., incompatible with other licenses, can my work be licensed under Licensed A by some licencee of the original work?

Comment: If you want to give away your copyright though (which is what PD really means), then I don't quite understand what you mean by "act like they owned the copyright". Technically, I could make trivial changes to the public domain work and then I have a rightful copyright on my version with the changes applied. You say you don't want to be credited but in fact it sounds like you do at least want some kind of notice retained. So I'd look into the other permissive licenses available that require this.

Comment: What I want is my work to be treated as if it was something that Shakespeare wrote. I can distribute _King Lear_, I can go on Amazon and sell a book with the contents of _King Lear_ with a proprietary license. What (at least I believe) I can't do is to go around saying _I_ wrote _King Lear_, or go to Disney and sell them the rights to _King Lear_ to make a movie for a 100 million dollars. Please correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: @ComputerUser121212 No, you absolutly **can** remove the "by shakespeare" but everybody would still recognize it, because it is famous.  Legally, you absolutely can claim "I wrote King Lear" - just nobody would believe you. And you could sell Disney a script for a King Lear screenplay for 100 million, just they would prefer to just chuck 15 bucks at Penguin Randomhouse and buy a copy, then have their own authors write it.

Comment: @ComputerUser121212 Based on your comments it seems likely that you want the CC-BY without the SA provision (i.e. the vanilla CC-BY license, not the SA one). I recommend you read section 3.a.1.A to see what the license requires when someone wants to use your CC-BY material. It accomplishes what you want to do already (i.e. no one can claim they are the author of your material, if you don't want that).

Comment: Thank you. I understand now better how copyright and Public Domain works, and thus will be able to better select under what license to license my works.

Comment: @ComputerUser121212 It's typical for a publishing contract to include a clause establishing the author as the sole owner of the work, that they have exclusive ability to transfer publishing rights, and that the work is not libelous, public domain, or a host of other things that would make the work legally or commercially unpublishable. You could sell Disney a copy of *King Lear* and possibly even claim you wrote it, but you'd be committing fraud if you claimed you were selling them the exclusive publishing rights to the work.

Comment: @Trish You can sell Disney a copy of King Lear for 100 million, sure, but surely trying to sell Disney specifically _the rights to King Lear_ for 100 million would qualify as fraud, right? I mean, comparing it to a famous historical work like that where everyone knows it's PD makes it less clear, but let's say I tried to sell Disney the rights to some obscure work from the 50s that was accidentally PD because of lack of copyright filing. If I know it's legally PD and I don't own the rights to it, wouldn't I be committing fraud, since I'm trying to sell something that I know I don't own?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### PD means you have **no** rights

No as in not a single right. [CC0/PD](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) means they can do **anything** legally: they can take the work, make a trivial edit and put their name on it [at least in addition] and you can't do anything. They can take the work, put a new cover on it, and put that work on amazon for 99.99 and using an ultra-restrictive other license. That's all covered under CC0:

> The person who associated a work with this deed has dedicated the work to the public domain **by waiving all of his or her rights to the work worldwide under copyright law, including all related and neighboring rights**, *to the extent allowed by law.*
> You can copy, modify, distribute and perform the work, even for commercial purposes, all without asking permission. See Other Information below.

By putting something in the public domain, you give up **all** the rights you have to the work and simultaneously give **everybody** the right to do with the work however they please - including any changes and relicensing.

The only way to prevent this requires you not to use CC0 PD but instead a copyleft license that requires attribution. Such as [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en).

#### But.... Author's Rights?

What I wrote above is true for the United States, but there are *several* countries that have a concept of un-sellable Author's rights - usually called moral rights. In **those** countries, claiming that someone else wrote the work isn't legally possible. Among those is [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), and the law there includes the right of attribution under the unwaiveable moral rights. Such laws are why I italicized a portion of the CC0 license deed: Not all countries allow you to give up all the rights, and the waiver is limited

> **to the extent allowed by law.**

Comment: I understand, but, is there a possibility of retaining the right of preventing someone to claim authorship without requiring attribution.

Comment: @ComputerUser121212 This is precisely what CC-"BY"-SA is before.  Note that there are two versions -- there is a CC-BY and a CC-BY-SA ("sharealike"). The ShareAlike version is commonly called "copyleft" because the requirement to give downstream people the same rights on your version is retained in future versions. However the CC-BY license without the SA does not have such a requirement, i.e. with that license you allow others to incorporate your materials into a (say) proprietary license (a non CC one).

Comment: The -BY is an abbreviation for "attribution required" (i.e. it's 'by' me).

Comment: In Germany, that is not the case. The author is the author, and that *cannot be changed.* The author may give rights to use the work, including without attribution, but giving a false attribution is different from giving no attribution.

Comment: The US does have [some moral rights](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/106A). However, they are waivable, unlike in some other countries, so CC0 likely does succeed in waiving them (the legal text of CC0 lists moral rights as "related rights" that are waived to the extent possible).

Comment: @o.m. that's part of the author's unwaiveable rights in Germany.

Comment: If (as suggested in the question) someone claimed publicly that you were not the author of the work, and that in fact they were, could there potentially be a cause of action for libel? As in, they are, falsely, calling you a liar/plagiarist, and thus damaging your otherwise good reputation?

Comment: Couldn't there be issues of fraud, if the false claim of authorship results in financial gain?